# Is there a default location for phpunit? or do I have to keep on exporting path in command line when I wish to use it?

Tags: php, debugging, zend-framework, phpunit, xdebug

Is there a default location to store the PHPUNIT extension?

I'm using symfony2 and each time I want to use phpunit I have to run this in terminal export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/symfony/app

Is this normal? or is there a way to make it always work, even if I update and rename my symfony folder to something else.

Is there a way to make it always work?

I'm using zend server ce and snow leopard 10.6+

Comment: Are you doing this because otherwise the symfony tests are not found? In which location do you invoke phpunit?

Comment: I invoke phpunit in symfony/app, it says app  not found until I use the full path to app. After when I try to run tests it can't find it.

Comment: Running phpunit alone brings up so information but when I attempt phpunit -c app/ it says app not found unless I run the full path to app then after it still can't fond my set controller anyway.

Comment: You might need to setup the includepath when invoking phpunit as well, see `phpunit --help`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I installed PHPUnit using the PEAR installer, it put `phpunit` in `/usr/bin` which was already on my path. This way I could type `phpunit` anywhere to run in the current directory.

- **What platform?**
  Ubuntu for me
- **How did you install PHPUnit?**
  `pear install phpunit/PHPUnit`
- **How does Symphony2 relate here?**
  Are you trying to run its tests or your own tests that use Symphony?

Comment: I think this worked for me. I dragged the phpunit file from my symfony app folder to my /usr/bin/ and it seems to work now. I don't have to export path or anything. Thanks

Comment: When I run phpunit -c app/ I get this error: Could not read "app/".

Comment: To answer your question I'm trying to run symfonys tests. I edited the path that is shown on the testing documentation to match the most current Acme directory and it still can't find the test controller

Comment: @Psychonetics: `-c` needs an XML configuration file, not a (incomplete) directory path. Use `phpunit --help` for a description of the command line parameters, you will find an include path option as well which might be useful for your setup.

Comment: If Symphony has its own PHPUnit tests, it most like has `bootstrap.php` and `phpunit.xml` configuration files. If you find those, `cd` into that directory and run `phpunit` without any arguments.